# My presentation won't show on the screen

Tags: mac, display, presentations

MacBook Air running 10.10. Until recently, doing presentations from my mac was easy. Turn up, plug in VGA, begin.

At a recent presentation, I could see the presentation on my screen, but not on the big screen. Worse, I could see my desktop on the big screen (toolbar, screen saver, system messages) - but I couldn't see the presentation.

I know this has something to do with screens...but what has gone wrong?

All assistance gratefully received. I am presenting - or hoping to present - in two hours...

Comment: some update somewhere probably changed your screen arrangement.  do as Jonsson says below.  The term you're looking for is "mirror".  You want to mirror your displays so what you see on your laptop is what you see on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fix the arrangement so the big screen is not the main screen.

System prefrances->dispays->arrangement and there you should be able to fix the problem